# 403 Forbidden message in postman

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Actually I am trying to send a mail using the SendGrid API key from the contact page. I am not able to understand what error is coming.

Let me know the actual error that I am facing. This will be greatly helpful to solve.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`403` error indicates that you have a permission issue with the API key that you are using. Please check your API key permissions whether it has access to the API you are trying to hit.